# Java's static/instance variables operation performance

Tags: java, static, instance

While reading Jack Shirazi's 'Java performance tuning', I came across the following statement:

"Instance and static variables can be up to an order of magnitude slower to operate on when
compared to method arguments and local variables."

Is this still applicable to Java 6/7? And if yes, what are the reasons behind it? (He explained something about having special bytecodes for accessing local variables/parameters but I did not understand it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key words here are *can be*. The issue is that locals and params (which are essentially a flavor of locals) *may* be in registers, while instance and static variables will ultimately end up in memory (they would get into registers for the time necessary to operate on them, but eventually back to the memory they go).

Answer (score 3):

Even if access were 10 times slower, it would only matter if you were in a very long loop.  And the Java Memory Model is pretty smart (sometime "too" smart) about optimizing memory access to instance variables.  If you use an instance var in a long loop, say, to sum 100,000 doubles, the JVM is very likely to  optimize that access and, in fact, *not* write the result to memory every single time.  The exception being volatile fields.  In fact, this whole optimization issue is why there are volatile fields.